# Angular Form Validates In Chrome But Not Firefox Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have a form that validates in in Chrome, but the bootsrap date picker is not validating in firefox using the mm/dd/yyyy format. If you enter it yyyy/dd/mm it validates. My datepicker html is below. Why would it validate and enable submit button in Chrome but not firefox with the same format?

```
<div  class="col-sm-6 lakerlink" ng-class="{'has-error' : lakerLookup.dateofbirth.$error.required || lakerLookup.dateofbirth.$error.minlength , 'has-success' : !lakerLookup.dateofbirth.$invalid && !lakerLookup.dateofbirth.$dirty}" >
            <input id="dateOfBirth" type="text" name="dateofbirth" class="form-control laker-date-input" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="10" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/y" ng-model="DateOfBirth" is-open="opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" tabindex="2" required/>
            <span class="input-group-btn link-date-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn date-picker-btn" ng-click="open($event)" tabindex="4"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Comment: if possible, can you add more code or provide jsfiddle?